# Am I applying the Monotone Convergence theorem correctly in this proof?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Im trying to prove $\int f(x) \mathbb{1}_{[-n,n]^c}\,\lambda(dx) = 0$, where $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and is in $L^1$. I thought of two possible (?) ways of doing this. My initial approach was to define $f_n(x) = f(x)\mathbb{1}_{[-n,n]}$, where we see that $f_n\rightarrow f$ and $|f_n|\leq |f_{n+1}|$, so we can apply the MCT. Then
$$\begin{align}
0 \leq \int |f(x) \mathbb{1}_{[-n,n]^c}(x)|\,\lambda(dx) &= \int |f(x)| \mathbb{1}_{[-n,n]^c}(x)\,\lambda(dx)\\
    &= \int \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}|f_n(x)| \mathbb{1}_{[-n,n]^c}(x)\,\lambda(dx)\\
    &= \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int |f_n(x)| \mathbb{1}_{[-n,n]^c}(x)\,\lambda(dx) \text{ (by MCT ??)}
\end{align}$$
As you can see I'm not sure if the MCT can even be applied there, what bothers me is the indicator function of $[-n,n]^c$.
My second approach was to use the fact that $f \,\mathbb{1}_{[-n,n]^c} = f - f_n$, and then try to manipulate the following expression
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int (f-f_n)\lambda(dx)$$
to eventually get to something with $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int |f_n|$ that we can apply the MCT and cancel with $\int |f|$. I'm pretty sure this problem is much easier than all of what i'm doing probably.

**NOTE: This is a homework question, im not looking for someone to post a full answer, I just need something to guide me cause i'm stuck.**

Comment: Ther are many errors. For example, $|f_n(x)| \mathbb{1}_{[-n,n]^c}$ is $\equiv 0$.

Comment: Also $|f_n|\leq |f_{n+1}|$ false, since $[-n-1,n+1]^c\subset [-n,n]^c$

Comment: @IrbidMath $f_n$ is defined over $[-n,n]$, I can't see how it it false.

Comment: @RaiBd you are correct I thought you defined $f_n = f 1_{[-n,n]^c}$